# Accessing Associated Values in an Array of Swift Enum in an Opaque Fashion

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I haven't really found what I need in the associated questions. That may be because I'm a bit thick, and didn't see it, but here's my quandary:

I have a computed property that returns an Array of enums with associated values.

The values are all the same types (in my use case, the type is a "flag"), but the enums are different.

I'd like to see if there was some way to cycle through the Array, looking at only the associated values, regardless of the enum type. I am attaching a small playground that shows what I mean:

```
enum A {
    case valueA(Int)
    case valueB(Int)
    case valueC(Int)
}

let a: [A] = [.valueA(0), .valueB(1), .valueC(2)]

for each in a {
    print(String(describing: each))
}

print();

// This works:

for each in a {
    if case let .valueA(value) = each {
        print(value)
    }
    if case let .valueB(value) = each {
        print(value)
    }
    if case let .valueC(value) = each {
        print(value)
    }
}

print();

// So does this:

for each in a {
    var value: Int = 0

    switch each {
    case .valueA(let val):
        value = val

    case .valueB(let val):
        value = val

    case .valueC(let val):
        value = val
    }

    print(value)
}

// What I want:

//for each in a {
//    if case let A(value) = each {
//        print(value)
//    }
//}
```

I want to be able to treat each member of the collection, and extract its flag, and then make a decision, based on that flag.

I know that I could do it with a big ol' switch statement, with all the enum values (second go), but it would be nice if there were some generic way to just access all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a slight modification on your enum:

```
enum A {
    case valueA(Int)
    case valueB(Int)
    case valueC(Int)

    var flag: Int {
        switch self {
        case .valueA(let flag),
             .valueB(let flag),
             .valueC(let flag):
            return flag
        }
    }
}
```

That makes any loop that just needs a flag trivial:

```
for each in a {
   print(each.flag)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would still have to test against the each case, but you could do

```
enum A {
    case valueA(Int)
    case valueB(Int)
    case valueC(Int)
}

let a: [A] = [.valueA(0), .valueB(1), .valueC(2)]

for each in a {

    switch each {
    case .valueA(let val), .valueB(let val), .valueC(let val):
        print(val)
    }
}
```

This would still apply if you have cases with associated values of different types:

```
enum Cases {
    case one(Int)
    case two(Int)
    case three(Int, String)
    case four(String)
    case five(String)
}

let testArray = [Cases.one(1), .two(2), .three(3, "three"),
                 .four("four"), .five("five")]

// Matching associated Ints
for value in testArray {

    switch value {

    case .one(let intVal), .two(let intVal), .three(let intVal, _):
        print(intVal)

    case .four(let strVal), .five(let strVal):
        print(strVal)
    }
}

// Matching associated Strings
for value in testArray {

    switch value {

    case .one(let intVal), .two(let intVal):
        print(intVal)

    case .three(_, let strVal), .four(let strVal), .five(let strVal):
        print(strVal)
    }

}

// Matching any type, cast to Any
for value in testArray {

    switch value {
    case .one(let anyVal as Any), .five(let anyVal as Any):
        print(anyVal)

    default:
        continue // skipping these cases
    }
}
```

The important takeaway is that you are binding the same var names in every statement whose value you are trying to match, meaning you can't match values that aren't available in ever statement:

```
switch ... {

// This won't work, because myInt is not defined in case .two 
// and myOtherInt isn't defined in case .one

case .one(let myInt), .two(let myOtherInt):
...

}
```

To add to @Kiril's answer, if you wanted computed values for cases with different types of associated values, you can define optional computed vars to return those values:

```
extension Cases {

    var intValue: Int? {

        switch self {

        case .one(let myInt), .two(let myInt), .three(let myInt, _):
            return myInt

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var strValue: String? {

        switch self {

        case .three(_, let myStr), .four(let myStr), .five(let myStr):

            return myStr

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey...not bad!
I'll greencheck that.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: I ended up rescinding the greencheck, because I thought that Kiril's method was a batter approach, but your is just as valid.

Comment: No worries!  Choose whatever is clearer and more intuitive to you.  I will say it's the same approach, except I didn't include a computed var for the value.  One thing to note is that, if you have associated values of different types (Int and String, for example) you wouldn't be able to create a non-optional computed var that returned the value for only some cases.  I'll add some cases to make this idea clearer.